# Oracle SQL "from" syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

What does it mean when I select from many tables with comma separated tables?

```
select * from table1,table2,table3
```

is it the same as join of left join or any other? How does it know how to join if I'm not specifying any id to join?

Comment: Without conditions, these are `cross joins`. Better not use this syntax, but stick to ANSI `JOIN` syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Oracle's legacy comma-join syntax. The ANSI/ISO equivalent is `CROSS JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1
       CROSS JOIN table2
       CROSS JOIN table3
```

However, if you have a `WHERE` clause then there may be more appropriate join conditions. For example:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1,table2,table3
WHERE  table1.id = table2.id
AND    table2.id = table3.id (+)
```

Converts to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1
       INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 ON (table2.id = table3.id)
```